# I want to do some change in the sorted method(internally) in python3.X

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to sort a dictionary on the basis of values while keeping the keys in the mind also. I want the keys to be in the order that I want (the keys should be in **reverse sorted fashion** for **same values**), but by default the keys are in sorted fashion for same values. How would I do that?

```
 dictionary = {'t':1, 'p':1, 'r':1, 'o':2, 'a':1}
 dictonary = sorted(dictonary.items(), key=itemgetter(1,0))
```

I get something like this.
('o', 2) ('t', 1) ('r', 1) ('p', 1) ('a', 1)
but I want  ('t', 1) ('r', 1) ('p', 1) ('a', 1) ('o', 2) that is for same values sort it reversely for same values.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have and what you want please?

Comment: There are plenty of examples of sorting a dictionary by value, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value without changing the internal `sort` and can easily be extended to cover the keys.

Comment: Your `sorted` output is reversed. By default `sorted` does smallest to largest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort on a `tuple` of both your `(value, key)` using `itemgetter` with multiple args, e.g.:

```
>>> d = {'t':1, 'p':1, 'r':1, 'o':2, 'a':1}
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1, 0))
[('a', 1), ('p', 1), ('r', 1), ('t', 1), ('o', 2)]
```

**Updated** OP changed expected output.
You can provide more control over the order with your own `lambda` function:

```
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)
[('t', 1), ('r', 1), ('p', 1), ('a', 1), ('o', 2)]
```

Comment: but i want it in reverse ascii or reverse sorted with key value

Comment: @ShailabSingh you should be clear you updated your expected results as this is what you originally asked for.

Comment: I just pasted the wrong one...but now i got the corect solution.